# Error while creating file by fs on Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, fs

I have a Node.js server and I'm trying to parse captcha by uploading bmp image to server. There are two problems I'm facing.

1. Image is not uploaded correctly. When I try to open Image it gives me error "BMP image has bogus header data".
2. Currently I'm reading buffer from uploaded data and parsing it to extract captcha string. Captcha string is arbitrary (results shows correct last 3 characters instead of 6).

This is code I'm using:

```
app.use (function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("statrt");  
    var data="";
    req.on('data', function(chunk) { 
        data += chunk;
    });
    req.on('end', function() {
        console.log("end"); 
        req.body = data;
        next();
    });
});

var DoneInSync = fibrous(function(buffer){
    var val = captcha.getCaptcha(buffer);
    console.log("this" + val);  
    return val;
});

app.post('/', function (req,res){

    buffer = new Buffer(req.body);
    fs.writeFileSync("captchas_ass.bmp", buffer);
    var val = DoneInSync.sync(buffer);
    res.write("Yoing -> " + val);
    res.end();

});
```

Captcha parser code runs perfectly, and is tested throughly offline.

**Main problem I'm facing is uploading BMP file to server** . Once done I can do this

```
var buf = fs.readFileSync("captcha.bmp");
```

and pass buf to `captcha.getCaptcha(buf)` and get result.

Can someone explain where it uploading is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your middleware is stringifying the incoming data, which it shouldn't be doing. Try this:

```
app.use (function(req, res, next) {
  var data = [];
  req.on('data', function(chunk) { 
    data.push(chunk);
  });
  req.on('end', function() {
    console.log("end"); 
    req.body = Buffer.concat(data); // `req.body` will be a Buffer
    next();
  });
});
```

This would only work if you're uploading the data as a "raw" POST request. If you're using something like `multipart/formdata`, this won't work either. For that you should use a middleware like [`multer`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer).

Comment: Tried this. Same output(only 2 characters). Same error(bogus header).

Comment: After Buffer.concat `fs.writeFileSync("captchas_ass.bmp", req.body);` this is what I have done .

Comment: To make requests I'm using [HTTPie](http://httpie.org) as `sudo http -f POST http://localhost:8080/ file@~/captcha3.bmp`

Comment: @LalitUmbarkar that command uses `multipart/formdata`, so you need special middleware to handle those types of uploads. Either that, or try this: `http post localhost:8080 < ~/captcha3.bmp` (I don't see why you would need to use `sudo`)

Comment: Thanks works now :) `sudo` is because I was once messing up with my permissions, and I need sudo for accessing anything outside my home dir.

Comment: Could you just give me some info on how would I do this with `multipart/formdata`, just in case I would need it some time. This error took me 10hrs. (I don't want to waste time again).

Comment: @LalitUmbarkar the link I provided to the `multer` package should be relatively straightforward.